# Access services information from within controller of .Net Core 3.1 API

Tags: api, jwt, asp.net-core-3.1

Building an API in .Net core 3.1. I am using a JWT authentication setup that I found somewhere online. Works great, but I am a bit stumped about how I can get information about the authenticated user from within a controller, in order to check permission to perform certain actions.

Within the ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs, I have the following code. I need access to either the "user" var (or userId var), produced by the userService, from within a controller. Or, of course, the context.Principal.Identity.Name value.

```
// configure strongly typed settings objects
var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);
// configure jwt authentication
var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            var userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
            var userId = int.Parse(context.Principal.Identity.Name);
            var user = userService.GetById(userId);
            if (user == null)
            {
                // return unauthorized if user no longer exists
                context.Fail("Unauthorized");
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
});
```

Comment: You can access the user principal from within the controller via the `User` property. Show an example of what it is you are trying to do in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the request has been authenticated, the user principal can be accessed within the controller via the [ControllerBase.User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.user?view=aspnetcore-3.1) Property

> Gets the ClaimsPrincipal for user associated with the executing action.

```
public System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal User { get; }
```

So assuming that the `IUserService` was injected into a controller, the principal can be accessed with the controller and used as needed.

```
public IActionResult SomeAction() {
    var userId = int.Parse(User.Identity.Name);
    var user = userService.GetById(userId);
    
    //...

}
```